# Core Plot: how to refresh graph which is embedded in a tab?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, core-plot

I have a graph embedded in tab. In the second tab, I have a table view display the same data in a table, using NSFetchResultController. 
The TabBar Controller is embedded in a Navigation Controller, which has an Add-Button in the right top of its navigation bar. This button modally segues a view controller, where the user can add a new object/record. 
While the table view is correctly updated, when the user adds a record, the tab with core plot graph is not refreshed.

Here is my code in the first tab (in viewWillAppear):

```
self.bmisForPlot = [[self fetchBmisForPlot] copy];
[graph reloadData];
```

where `self.bmisForPlot`is an array carrying the data for the graph.

In the Tabbar Controller (which I subclassed):

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {
    NSLog(@"controller class: %@", NSStringFromClass([viewController class]));
    if ([NSStringFromClass([viewController class]) isEqualToString:@"MRBMIKurveViewController"]) 
    {
        MRBMIKurveViewController *kurveViewController = (MRBMIKurveViewController *) viewController;
        kurveViewController.bmisForPlot = [[kurveViewController fetchBmisForPlot] copy];
        [kurveViewController.graph reloadData];
        NSLog(@"switched to MRIKurveViewController");
    }
}
```

This method is called, when the user switches tabs, but the graph is NOT refreshed?

Is there a way to force refreshing a graph?

The table view gets updated because its data source is a NSFetchedResultsController, but I don't know if and how can I use a NSFetchedResultsController in conjunction with a core plot graph?

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You should `reloadData` for the plot, not the graph itself:

`[kurveViewController.thePlot reloadData];`

Comment: No, it does not work. However, what I have found: The datasource for the core plot isn't updated. The data source for the table view is updated, as it is a NSFetchedResultsController. As far as I can tell, I either need something similiar to a NSFetchedResultsController for core plot, or a way to force refreshing the core plot's data source when the modal-segueed view controller, which creates a new object/record is dismissed.

Comment: Did you add the delegate and datasource:

`@interface MyReportViewController : UIViewController <CPTBarPlotDataSource, CPTBarPlotDelegate>`

Put a breakpoint to `(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot` and `(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index` and see if they are called.